# Implementing a head-specifiable sequence Nothing construct

Tags: performance-tuning, pattern-matching

So in [this ILD video](https://www.twitch.tv/videos/201518017?t=00h42m42s) some WRI people discuss a user-suggestion of a Nothing-like construct that the user called `AutoFlatten`.

Per the first part of the discussion, the idea is something like this:

```
{a, b, AutoFlatten[{c, d, e}], f}
(*Out*)
{a, b, c, d, e, f}
```

Which they note is like kinda like a `NothingSequence`

I looked at that and thought that much better would be something that could work with arbitrary head. I.e.

```
h[a, b, c, NothingSequence[h[1, 2, 3]]]
(*Out*)
h[a, b, c, 1, 2, 3]
```

And the trivial implementation of this is:

```
NothingSequence /:
 h_[a___, NothingSequence[h_[b___]], c___] :=

 h[a, b, c]
```

Which does what I want:

```
List@NothingSequence[{1, 2, 3}]

{1, 2, 3}

Hold@NothingSequence[Hold[1, 2, 3]]

Hold[1, 2, 3]
```

But this is super slow:

```
With[{seqs =
   NothingSequence /@
    (Hold @@@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10000}])
  },
 First[RepeatedTiming[Hold @@ seqs]]
 ]

0.021
```

Is there any hope of speeding this up or is the pattern too general?

Comment: Why do you call that "Nothing-like"? That's confusing. `Nothing` gets merely skipped when put into a list. This is indeed about flattening out list...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher it's a disappearing construct based on the head of the its parent expression like `Nothing` is. That's the basis for my using of `Nothing`-like. And naively one would implement `Nothing` at top-level in the same way.

Comment: Close to `Flat`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following approach avoids pattern matching `h[a, NothingSequence[h[b]], c]` over and over again:

```
NothingSequence /: h_[a___, NothingSequence[h_[b___]], c___] := h @@ Replace[
    {a,b,c},
    NothingSequence[h[d__]] -> Sequence[d],
    {1}
]
```

For your test case:

```
With[{seqs = NothingSequence /@ (Hold @@@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10000}])},
    First[RepeatedTiming[Hold @@ seqs]]
]
```

> 0.0052

On my computer this is 3-4 times faster.

**Addendum**

We can compare the speed to just using [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten):

```
seqs = Hold @@@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10000}];
nseqs = NothingSequence /@ seqs;

r1 = Hold @@ nseqs; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = Flatten[Hold @@ seqs, 1, Hold]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.0050, Null}
>
> {0.0022, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Nice. I might substitute some holding construct like `uselessSafeHead[a, b, c]` for `{a, b, c}`, where `uselessSafeHead` is `HoldAllComplete`, but only 2x slower than `Flatten` is pretty good.

Comment: `NothingSequence /: expr : h_[___, NothingSequence@h_@___, ___] :=
    FlattenAt[FlattenAt[Unevaluated@expr, #], #]&@
        Position[Unevaluated@expr, Unevaluated@NothingSequence@h@___, {1}, Heads -> False]` is slightly faster on my computer.